# Trying to rewrite a html container with grid, to flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

So I have a container made with grid, but exporing it into PDF doesn't support it so I have to rewrite it to Flexbox. (The rest of the page is written with flex and works absolutely fine).

Basicly I need a 3 column layout, where the 2 columns on the left are just basicly a list in both column:

Column 1:
Item
Item
Item

Column 2: Item item item

Column 3: Bigger rectangle, which will hold a chart canvas inside of it.
(See added screenshot)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZQv8.png

The section, grid, story, etc is mainly for putting it all in one container and centering it inside the page, that works really well. (Existing code), but the 'container'-class part with scores, and scorebox is where it's in css grid, and where the trickery is.

```
The code as of now:

<section class="story story--spaceous">
    <div class="hero__compact-inner">
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="grid__row">
                <div class="grid__col">
                    <h2 class="hero__subtitle">
                        <span id="header-title"></span>
                    </h2>
                    <p class="story__intro">
                        <span id="header-customerName"></span>
                    </p>
                    <p class="story__intro">
                        <span id="header-description"></span>
                    </p>

                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="score1">
                            Laag 1: Bewustzijn <div id="header-awarenessProgression"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="score2">
                            Laag 2: Beleid <div id="header-policyProgression"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="score3">
                            Laag 3: Monitoring <div id="header-monitoringProgression"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="score4">
                            Laag 4: Data Security <div id="header-dataSecurityProgression"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="score5">
                            Laag 5: Applicatie <div id="header-applicationProgression"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="score6">
                            Laag 6: EndPoint Security <div id="header-endPointSecurityProgression"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="score7">
                            Laag 7: Netwerk/Systeem <div id="header-networkSystemProgression"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="score8">
                            Laag 8: Fysiek <div id="header-physicalProgression"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="score-box">
                            <div class="chart--donut"><canvas id="header-totalScore"></canvas></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="header-lastPublished"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

And CSS:

        .container {
            width: 1000px;
            margin: 30px auto;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 40px);
            grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
            height: 260px;
        }

        .score1 {
            grid-row: 1/2;
            grid-column: 1/2;
        }

        .score2 {
            grid-row: 1/2;
            grid-column: 2/3;
        }

        .score3 {
            grid-row: 2/3;
            grid-column: 1/2;
        }

        .score4 {
            grid-row: 2/3;
            grid-column: 2/3;
        }

        .score5 {
            grid-row: 3/4;
            grid-column: 1/2;
        }

        .score6 {
            grid-row: 3/4;
            grid-column: 2/3;
        }

        .score7 {
            grid-row: 4/5;
            grid-column: 1/2;
        }

        .score8 {
            grid-row: 4/5;
            grid-column: 2/3;
        }

        .score-box {
            grid-row: 1/-1;
            grid-column: 3/4;
            background-color: #e3e33e;
            height: 300px;
            width: 300px;
        }
```

So I need this idea to be in Flexbox. Any idea what's the quickest win?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone who's ridden the strugglebus that is html to pdf conversion, make sure that flexbox actually works with whatever method you're using first. When I had to do the same thing for work several months ago, I ended up starting with grid, switching to flexbox, and then finally redoing the whole thing with plain html tables.

To answer your question about flexbox though, I just put all your scores in a container by themselves and defined a width for that, while defining both the containing element and the list of scores as `display: flex`. Here's the code:

```
<section class="story story--spaceous">
    <div class="hero__compact-inner">
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="grid__row">
                <div class="grid__col">
                    <h2 class="hero__subtitle">
                        <span id="header-title"></span>
                    </h2>
                    <p class="story__intro">
                        <span id="header-customerName"></span>
                    </p>
                    <p class="story__intro">
                        <span id="header-description"></span>
                    </p>

                    <div class="container">
                      <div class="score-list">
                        <div class="score">
                            Laag 1: Bewustzijn <div id="header-awarenessProgression"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="score">
                            Laag 2: Beleid <div id="header-policyProgression"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="score">
                            Laag 3: Monitoring <div id="header-monitoringProgression"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="score">
                            Laag 4: Data Security <div id="header-dataSecurityProgression"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="score">
                            Laag 5: Applicatie <div id="header-applicationProgression"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="score">
                            Laag 6: EndPoint Security <div id="header-endPointSecurityProgression"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="score">
                            Laag 7: Netwerk/Systeem <div id="header-networkSystemProgression"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="score">
                            Laag 8: Fysiek <div id="header-physicalProgression"></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="score-box">
                        <div class="chart--donut"><canvas id="header-totalScore"></canvas></div>
                      </div>
                      <div id="header-lastPublished"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>


<style>
.container {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  height: 260px;
  display: flex;
}

.score-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 75%;
}

.score {
  width: 50%;
}

.score-box {
  background-color: #e3e33e;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Cheers mate, but sadly it doesn't have the resulted outcome.How'd it look for you?
With your code and styling it looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/HYtW1Ou.png

Comment: Here's the codepen I used: https://codepen.io/deece/pen/ExxpQdo